# Python Requests using socks5 proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, python-requests, socks

I have deployed an AWS ec2 instance to use a proxy. I have edited the security policies and have allowed my machine to have access to the server. I am using port 22 for SSH, and port 4444 for the proxy. For some reason I still can not start a session using the proxy.

The code:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'user-agent' : user_agent}
proxies = {
    'http' : 'socks5h://ec2-ip-address-here.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:4444',
    'https' : 'socks5h://ec2-ip-address-here.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:4444',
}

print(session.get('https://www.ipchicken.com/', headers=headers, proxies=proxies).content)
```

The error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.ipchicken.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x107a09048>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOL2eg0g0Ng for setting up the server. Thanks to all of those who reply in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You need to be using `socks5h://` for your `http` and `https` proxies.

I get this error on macOS when using `socks5://`.